# What plausible reasons are there why the startup time for a large program would get SLOWER when I add more RAM into a Linux PC?

Tags: linux, performance, caching, cpu-architecture, ram

I have a large C++/OpenGL program (running under Linux) that takes several minutes to start up (it's loading a LOT of files) - it ends up consuming around 70Gbytes of RAM.  We've been running it on a 96Gbyte machine - and recently upgraded to 128Gbytes.  To our surprise, the startup time INCREASED by about 30 seconds.

We've checked that the RAM clock speed didn't change - the new RAM chips are the same type as the existing ones and the problem is very repeatable.  We've checked for RAM faults (there aren't any) and that none of the CPU cache properties have changed.  The amount of RAM our program consumes hasn't changed before/after the memory increase.

We'd expect the startup time to be about the same - but this is not a small increase.

Comment: What's your CPU and memory configuration exactly? What DIMMs are you using? It appears to me that the startup phase of your program is bandwidth-bound. So if the increase in total RAM caused the maximum bandwidth to decrease, then obviously performance will deteriorate. Generally, for optimal bandwidth you want to install one or two DIMMs of the same type in every channel of every CPU in the system. More DIMMs will only improve performance if more RAM capacity is needed (so as reduce disk accesses), which is clearly not case here.

Comment: @ Steve Have you considered memory mapping the files (unless you need to read each file entirely and immediately)? @HadiBrais Is it possible to decrease BW by adding more RAM? Maybe in a NUMA machine when locality cannot be satisfied?

Comment: @MargaretBloom Yes. Adding more DIMMs may reduce the memory frequency due to the increased power load (but the OP said this is not happening) and may increase the memory controller management overhead (which steals bandwidth from data). Changing the type of DIMM (from RDIMM to LRDIMM) may increase capacity per DIMM, but at the expense of bandwidth. One other case I can think of is when adding a DIMM that causes the memory configuration to be unbalanced across CPU sockets or across memory controllers of the same socket or channels of the same controller.

Comment: @MargaretBloom - we are reading the files entirely and immediately.   It might make sense to memory-map them - but at the moment, I'm looking to understand why adding RAM makes it slower.  It's always better to understand a problem than to wave a magic wand and make it go away.

Comment: @Steve More often than not, people read a whole file just to have it in a buffer and don't bother implementing an on demand logic. Mem mapping is not a magic wand, it is a cleaver approach: the OS makes you *believe* it has read the whole file while it has not (doing the on-demain part for you). BTW, why do you think it's a RAM issue? IO is obviously bound by the disks BW (not even close to the DRAM BW). The 30s delay could be due to other environmental effects, like the OS changing paging policy.

Comment: @HadiBrais I'm not aware of any management overhead the MC could incur in with more DIMMs. The TAD, SAD and mem mapper registers are set at boot (or once when the DIMMs are hot-plugged) and then, I assume, the physical address translation is constant time or at least well within the period of the DRAM clock.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Right, all of that is not relevant. It looks like that the term I used was misleading. I was referring to the rank-to-rank switching penalty where two back-to-back commands to different ranks take more time on the channel's bus than to the same rank. A larger number of ranks increases the probability of timing conflicts between the ranks (whether they belong to the same DIMM or different DIMMs).